# ModelState.IsValid is false when I have a nullable parameter and send it as null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, nullable, c#-11.0

[Here the nullable parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgg7h.png)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Validation;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace RenoshopBee.Models
{

    public class CreditCard
    {
        
        [DataType(DataType.CreditCard),
         MaxLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Credit card number must be 12 numbers"),
         MinLength(12, ErrorMessage = "Credit card number must be 12 numbers")]
        public string CNumber { get; set; }
        [RegularExpression("^\\d{3}$",ErrorMessage ="CCV must be 3 numbers")]

        public int CCV { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ExpireDate { get; set; }
        [Key]
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [ValidateNever]
        public Customer customer { get; set; }


    }
}
```

what you see is the code of the CreditCard
The use can skip enterening the Credit Card information when SignUp so it will be null credit card

[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4Sth.png)

so what to do to skip the validation of null credit card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what you see is the code of the CreditCard The use can skip enterening
> the Credit Card information when SignUp so it will be null credit
> card. so what to do to skip the validation of null credit card?

Well, you might wonder,  `ModelState.IsValid` construct and its executed before hitting the controller so, `IsValid` always be false unless you define any property nullable explicitely in your model, threfor, yes of course here in controller `CreditCard?` nullable would ignored. As [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state) and [model validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state) occur before the execution of a controller action or a Razor Pages handler method. It's the app's responsibility to inspect `ModelState.IsValid` and react appropriately. So you should use `credit card` nullablity inside your model rather in controller because compiler comes first on the model then the controller. Thus, if you would like to `CreditCard` property to be null, therefore, you should set the property null in model not in controller.

**Model**

```cs
public class CreditCard
{
  
    public string? CNumber { get; set; }
    public int? CCV { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ExpireDate { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    [ValidateNever]
    public Customer? customer { get; set; }


}
```

**Note**: As you can see I have set `public string? CNumber` means while submission this propeerty will not be validate. Hence, it will not be considerate on controller as well. If you need more information, you could [have a look on our official document here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state)

**Output**

Let's check above statements in action, Here, be informed that, I haven't set any nullable annotation on property in model and now if I submit with null value it will not hit the controller as you can see below:

[image]

Soon after, when I set nullability on `CNumber` it's hitting controller even with null value. As can be seen below:

[image]

**Note:** Please [have a look on this official document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#model-state)

Comment: Thank you this way worked but should I make the validation in the frontend instead of the model itself

Comment: You are welcome, well, it deepends if model validation somewhat doesn't meet your requirement in that case you could consider but update to now I think its seems alright.